# How to stretch 50% width and 100% height of content icon span element based on container height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a below html structure. Container have some dynamic height and width. Based on container fonticon1 and fonticon2 split the width and occupy the 100% height.

```css
.fonticon1,
.fonticon2 {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.icon1:before,
.fonticon2:before {
  content: '\e34c';
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
    <span class="fonticon1">
        <span class="icon1"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="fonticon2"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put [`display: flex;`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on your `container` so that its block-level children align side-by-side.

Set the children to `display: block;`, `height: 100%;`, and `width: 50%;`.

Demo below. I've added some necessary styling for demo purposes. `Container` is indicated by the red border, and the children by the black borders.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.fonticon1,
.fonticon2 {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* UNNECESSARY DEMO STUFF */
.container { border: 1px solid red; height: 50px; }
.fonticon1, .fonticon2 { border: 1px solid black; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<span class="container">
    <span class="fonticon1">
        <span class="icon1"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="fonticon2"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use container as display: block; and without flex you can put 
float:left in .fonticon1,.fonticon2 this will divide your span in 2 block

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
display: block;
border: 1px #ddd solid;
overflow: hidden;
}

.fonticon1,
.fonticon2 {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
float: left;
}

.icon1:before,
.fonticon2:before {
  content: '\e34c';
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
    <span class="fonticon1">
        <span class="icon1"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="fonticon2"></span>
</span>
```